# Simple weather app breaking at weather.main.temp variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, openweathermap

I'm building a really basic weather app with React hooks, codesandbox.io and OpenWeatherAPI.
It's breaking at `const temp = forecast.main.temp;` and returning "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')" It actually does run when I initially write it but breaks if I add another variable or have to edit the temp variable in any way.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../styles.css";
import CityCard from "./cityCard";

export default function GetWeather() {

  const [city, setCity] = useState('');
  const [forecast, setForecast] = useState([]);

  const getCity = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

  //API variables 
  const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=${APIkey}`;
  
  //fetch response
  try {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();
  setForecast(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

};

  return (
    //basic input form to search by city
    <div>
      <h1 className="title">Weather App</h1>
      <CityCard forecast={forecast} />
      <form className="form" onSubmit={getCity}>
      <label className="label" htmlFor="city">
      <p>Search by City</p>
      </label>
      <input 
        className="input" 
        type="text" 
        name="query place"
        placeholder="i.e. Seattle"
        value={city} onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
        >
      </input>
      <button 
      className="button" 
      type="submit"
      >Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CityCard

```
import React from "react";
import "../../src/styles.css";

export default function CityCard({ forecast }) {
  //pass props to cards
  const cityName = forecast.name;
  const temp = forecast.main.temp;

  return (
      <div className="card-container">
        <p className="card-title">{cityName}</p>
        <p>Temp: {temp} </p>
      </div>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The initial `forecast` state is declared as an array:

```
const [forecast, setForecast] = useState([]);
```

and passed to `CityCard` on `forecast` prop:

```
<CityCard forecast={forecast} />
```

then accessed as if it were an object:

```
function CityCard({ forecast }) {
  //pass props to cards
  const cityName = forecast.name;  // OK, undefined
  const temp = forecast.main.temp; // Not OK, can't access temp of undefined

  return (
      <div className="card-container">
        <p className="card-title">{cityName}</p>
        <p>Temp: {temp}</p>
      </div>

  );
}
```

## Solution

Use Optional Chaining operator to protect against null/undefined property accesses.

```
function CityCard({ forecast }) {
  //pass props to cards
  const cityName = forecast?.name;
  const temp = forecast?.main?.temp;

  return (
      <div className="card-container">
        <p className="card-title">{cityName}</p>
        <p>Temp: {temp}</p>
      </div>

  );
}
```

Or wait to render `CityCard` when there's a valid `forecast` data to display.

```
const [forecast, setForecast] = useState();

...

{forecast?.name && forecast?.main?.temp && <CityCard forecast={forecast} />}
```

[OpenWeather JSON API response](https://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response! The optional chaining operator does fix the problem for now and is really useful to keep in mind. As for why the array is passed as an object, I have no idea lol, I'm using this app to learn props and api's. Thanks again